# Variable 'interface' might not have been initialized

Tags: java, spring, morphia

I am trying to build a `Morphia` and `Spring` application using a template from another project and I am getting the following error

```
Variable 'assetRepository' might not have been initialized
```

The `AssetRepository` is an interface

```
package code.nithin.repository;

import code.nithin.entity.Asset;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Key;

public interface AssetRepository {
    public Key<Asset> save(Asset asset);
}
```

and the `AssetController` is

```
package code.nithin.controllers;

import code.nithin.entity.Asset;
import code.nithin.repository.AssetRepository;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Key;

public class AssetController{

    public String saveAsset(String URL){
        AssetRepository assetRepository;
        Asset test = new Asset(1, System.currentTimeMillis(),"https://example.com");

        String returnString = assetRepository.save(test).getId();

    }
}
```

The entity is

```
package code.nithin.entity;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity("asset")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Asset {

    @Id
    public ObjectId _id;

    public int version;
    public long timestamp;
    public String URL;

    public Asset(){}

    public Asset(int version, long timestamp, String URL) {
        this.version = version;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    public ObjectId get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(ObjectId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }
}
```

The project I am referring to implements the same as

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner init(AssetRepository assetRepository){
    return (args) -> {
        Asset test = new Asset(1, 123456789632541 ,"https://example.com");
        System.out.println(assetRepository.save(test).getId());
    };
}
```

The project I am referring to throws no error.

Stack trace

```
Error:(19, 28) java: variable assetRepository might not have been initialized
    Error:(21, 5) java: missing return statement
    /home/signzy/code/java/cubereum/boilerplate/src/main/java/code/cubereum/controllers/AssetController.java
    Information:javac 1.8.0_181 was used to compile java sources
    Information:1/9/18 2:58 PM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 1 s 730 ms
    Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'boilerplate_main'
```

Answer (score 0):

`saveAsset()` has a local `assetRepository` (never set) which hides the static global one.

Remove the local one and it should work.

After seeing the stack trace it is obviously as I said above:

```
public String saveAsset(String URL){
        AssetRepository assetRepository;
        Asset test = new Asset(1, System.currentTimeMillis(),"https://example.com");

        String returnString = assetRepository.save(test).getId();

    }
```

1. You have a local `AssetRepository` that you never set and so you get "variable assetRepository might not have been initialized"
2. The function returns a string but you have no `return` statement so you get "missing return statement"

   ```
   public String saveAsset(String URL){
       Asset test = new Asset(1,  System.currentTimeMillis(),"https://example.com");
       return assetRepository.save(test).getId();
    }
   ```

Comment: Hey I removed the global one and even the constructor to have a local one itself. And I've edited the question as well. The same error occours.

Comment: Include the stack trace!

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from this code:

```
public String saveAsset(String URL){
    AssetRepository assetRepository;
    Asset test = new Asset(1, System.currentTimeMillis(),"https://example.com");

    String returnString = assetRepository.save(test).getId();

}
```

You have an assetRepository which is not initialized. And then you try to do

```
assetRepository.save(test).getID();
```

Since assetRepository is not initialized, this can be a problem.

EDIT: 
AssetRepository is an Interface, so you can't initalize your assetRepository variable with it.

However, you should have somewhere an other class, which implements AssetRepository and defines the method save(Asset asset). It should looks like that:

```
public class Foo implements AssetRepository{
    public Foo(){
        //Constructor for this class
    }

    public Key<Asset> save(Asset asset){
        //some code here
        //this defines the method declared in the Interface
    }
}
```

Then, to initialize your variable, you do that:

```
AssetRepository assetRepository = new Foo();
```

Comment: How do i initialize an Interface?

Comment: If it's an interface, you should have subclasses. You intialize it with new Subclass();

Comment: Didn't understand.

Comment: well, usually an Interface is a class containing methds with empty bodies. Then you have others classes, which **implements** the interface, and defines the methods. You should have somewhere a class which implements "AssetRepository" and defines the method "save(Asset asset)". If not, you can't initialize the interface.

Comment: Given you're using spring, you probably need to inject/autowire it.